# Object is of type 'unknown'.(2571) when using map() with array of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Although I have googled this error and seen many posts about the topic, I still couldn't figure out how to fix the error.

I'm fetching some data through external API call that comes with the following signture

```
const properties: { [x: string]: unknown;} | { [x: string]: unknown;}[] | undefined
```

When I try to map the object with

```
const myMap = properties?.map((item: { [x: string]: unknown;} | { [y: string]: unknown;}) => { return { [item.x as string]: item.y } });
```

I got the a.m. typescript error at `properties?.map`

Am I missing a simple thing here? **Appreciate any help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`properties` can be an object or array of objects of undefined. You cannot use `map` on an object. So you get that error.

if you want to use `Array.prototype.map`, you could create another variable and make sure it is of type `{ [x: string]: unknown;}[] | undefined`:

```
const arrayOfProperties = properties
  ? Array.isArray(properties)
    ? properties
    : [properties]
  : undefined;
```

Comment: Thanks you for the Array hint, but mapping yields to array of undefined pairs like so.. 
[ {undefined: undefined}, {undefined: undefined}.. ]

Comment: Oh I didn't read the map function in your question. The objects has two properties, which you want to use the value of one (`x`) as the key and the value of the other one (`y`) as its value? This is how you want to transform each object?

Comment: Exactly, it's an array of key/value object [ { x1: 'x1-value'}, { x2: 'x2-value'},..] that I need to render in <li> tags. and stuck on that

Comment: I didn't get it.  Let's say the array of properties is equal to `[{x1: 'x1-value'}, {x2: 'x2-value'}, {x3: 'x3-value'}]`. How do you want to transform it? What should be the output?

Comment: <ul>
<li key='x1'> x1 = x1-value</li>
<li key='x2'> x2 = x2-value</li>
</ul>

Comment: Does [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-benz-qlrg20?file=/src/App.tsx) answer your question? I'm still not sure whether objects can have more than one property or not. But you can handle it however you want.

Comment: Yes, I just added fragments to function. like so <>{key}={value}</>, Thanks a lot.